Grouping issues under 1 EPIC in the Jira Kanban board
I have a project consisting of 8 EPICs and 61 issues. Each issue is linked to one of the EPIC. In the Jira Kanban board I currently have a column called "ToDo" that contains all 69 items. But the order in which these items are listed is defined by the order in which I defined the items. What I would like is to present each issue underneath its EPIC, preferable even with an indent compared to the position of the EPIC.
Is this somehow possible in Jira or do I need to drag and drop each issue to the right position in the Todo list?

You can configure the board to use swimlanes. One of the swimlane-bases is "Epics", so items are put into a swimlane by one epic.
Drawback is that you will not have the epics shown as cards in the board anymore with this - even those without any issues assigned, they will not even show up as empty swimlane.
